# CSS Marquee adding more lines of text

Tags: html, css, animation, marquee

I created a marquee using the help of this article - http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/

but I can't figured out how to add more than 2 lines of text that show.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

The author of the article doesn't seem to answer any questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the relevant code that you have used, and what you have tried

Comment: Here is a demo. https://jsfiddle.net/Lff9ab0d/1/ Only thing I have really tried is copying the existing code and altering it. *Semi-beginner developer here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/976xpLvo/

All I have done is add another marquee and given it a unique seperate id. Then, I have used `position: relative` to position it

```
<div class="marquee">
    ...
</div>
<div class="marquee" id="second">
    ...
</div>
```

Then I have styled it:

```
#second {
    position: relative;
    top: -24px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, any luck in having more than 2 sections of text appear in the same marquee? Like ----Text 1-------Text 2-------Text3---- Thanks!!

Comment: Ohh, sorry I misunderstood your question @TrTv I'm afraid I'm not sure, it seems made for two sections of text

Comment: Thanks Joe! I think I'm gonna scrap the whole thing.

Comment: Awh, I'm sure there must be a different method that allows for three sections? I guess there must be a javascript/jQuery solution if you can use them? @TrTv

Comment: Looking into it now. This method doesn't respond well at all in mobile anyway. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: No problem! If my method helped in any way would you mind upvoting it, or marking it as the answer?